# jQuery ajaxSuccess and ajaxError behavior

Tags: ajax, jquery

The global events ajaxSuccess and ajaxError are not working properly for me. I disconnected my Internet connection and ajaxSuccess handler executes with xhr.status=0, and ajaxError is not executing at all. I need you to confirm if this is bug or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the code of what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug, a `0` being "successful" was originally added because Opera returns a 304 as a 0, or at least used to, [you can see it in a comment in the jQuery core code here](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.2/src/ajax.js#L553).

However if you look [at the main branch, you'll see this `status == 0` exception has been removed](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L634) for the jQuery 1.5 release, so it's already fixed and you'll see this fix in 1.5.

Comment: So it's a bug. I also suspected that.

Comment: @Nazaf - I'd say so, or more accurately it's a code check that does more harm than good, so you could see it from either side....and welcome :)